# Laravel model create relationships twice between two tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to create relation between two tables, users and messages in Laravel models, as the user can send a message to another user so that I have two foreign-keys (**fromUser_id** and **toUser_id**) as shown in the image below.

[image]

For the first relation it is straightforward that I will create a function with the name messages

```
public function messages(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Message', 'fromUser_id');
}
```

However I do not know how to name the second relation as far as I know it should be messages too, according to the standard naming of Laravel, which will obviously issue an error as we have the first function with the same name.

```
public function messages(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Message', 'toUser_id');
}
```

Would you please let me know what should I name it and how this will affect the models.

Comment: Just use nice descriptive names. No problem with any standard naming with that.

Comment: What will confuse laravel is `'fromUser_id'` or `'toUser_id'` not the name of the function, name it as you please :) !

Comment: @Maraboc Do you think 'fromUser_id' or 'toUser_id' will produce any problem when I start to create controllers

Comment: no i mean laravel will check what you added as foreing key in the second arg not the name of the function ! and it's ok with @Marcin answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you should not use simple `messages` as relationship but rather use `receivedMessages` and `sentMessages` like this:

```
public function sentMessages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Message', 'fromUser_id');
}

public function receivedMessages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Message', 'toUser_id');
}
```

Comment: My question is: will changing the name from messages to any other name confuse the laravel model or it is ok to name it as I want to

Comment: No, you can use names for relationships as you want so there won't be any problem here.